# How can i detect white blobs (Rectangles) in a black and white image?

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

Im doing a numberplate extraction where i have managed to erode the number plate area and I need to detet the rectangular numberplate using blobcount. But can I use it on a black and white image?

I am using Aforge.Net library for this.

My whole idea is to identify the postion of the numberplate corners and extract it from a colour image and then use an OCR.

Hope this helps

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using AForge a little recently and ran across a good blob detection example (though I haven't tried it myself). It uses some BlobCounter and recognizes glyphs. Anyway, [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/glyph_recognition/) it is.

Hope this helps, and good luck if it doesn't!

Comment: I'm not really sure about using the glyphs. but what i noticed was that it throws an exception when you use a binary image to detect white rectangles.  The exception thrown says "a graphics image cannot be created from an indexed format". is there a work around this?

Comment: Ok @hypertunes, I found a link that might help: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rrraman/graphicsObject08232007102733AM/graphicsObject.aspx

Comment: @SuperPrograman...Thanks alot mate you are a lifesaver :D worked like a charm for me :) cheers